# Why is there no smooth value from ADXL335?

Tags: sensors, accelerometer

I have written this code to read x-acceleration from ADXL335.

1. Why is the value toggling between 342, 343, 344 even at rest? Is there anything I need to do to get a smooth curve? [image: reference here]
2. How to increase resolution? (I'm using a Mega 2560)

---

```
int Xcurr,Ycurr,Zcurr;
int Xpre=0,Ypre=0,Zpre=0;
int res=0;
// these constants describe the pins. They won't change:
const int groundpin = A1;
// analog input pin 4 -- ground
const int powerpin = A0;
// analog input pin 5 -- voltage
const int xpin = A3;
// x-axis of the accelerometer
const int ypin = A2;
// y-axis
const int zpin = A4;
// z-axis (only on 3-axis models)
const int stpin = A5;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(groundpin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(powerpin, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(groundpin, LOW);
  digitalWrite(powerpin, HIGH);
  pinMode(stpin, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(stpin, LOW);
}

void loop() {
  Xcurr=analogRead(xpin);
  Serial.print(Xcurr);Serial.print("\n");
  delay(100);
}
```

Comment: It's called LSB noise, and it is what the ADC does. Just average the values over time (rolling average) to smooth it.

Answer (score 1):

It is called moving average, the calculations you can use to prevent such problems can be found at [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average)

In principle, what you do is take the average over the last x measurements to take away the peaks.